# Are current and past events pages using the same string for case when there are no events?

Tags: feature-request, localization, russian-stackoverflow, transifex

I'm not sure about past events: https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=past

But https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=current uses text:

> There are no events being planned right now.

Key in transifex: `557602e46ca673366a2e1469d556c02f`.

On SOru: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=current and https://ru.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=past both pages are using the same text (which is relevant only for current events):

> На данный момент, у нас нет планов

And in traducir I found only one string: https://ru.traducir.win/string/3304

Are current and past events pages using the same string for case when there are no events? If so, could you separate them?